Using mod_rewrite to redirect all requests to another directory
This should be easy but apparently isn't.
My http.conf points mydomain.com to "/var/html/www".
In "/var/html/www" is a folder called "production" that contains another folder called "version10.7" which contains all html-files, including an index.html.

/var/html/www

/production

/version10.7

/index.html







When someone enters mydomain.com in the address bar of their browser, I want

that "mydomain.com/version10.7/index.html" appears in their address bar and
that, internally, files in (from the base dir) /production/version10.7/ are being used to serve requests made to mydomain.com

My .htaccess located in "/var/html/www" reads:
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=307]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /version10\.7/index.html [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/production/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /production/$1 [L]

This is currently working with one caveat related to the last set of RewriteCond and RewriteRule. If someone enters "mydomain.com/production/version10.7" in their browser, they are not redirected to "mydomain.com/version10.7/index.html" like anyone else that enters just "mydomain.com", but they see "mydomain.com/production/version10.7/index.html" in their browser (note the /production/ in between). For the life of me I can't figure out how to get rid of that issue with only this single .htaccess file. When I remove the condition
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/production/

which serves as a crutch to enable this to work, or reuse the condition of the rule before this one
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]

it causes an internal server error (I suspect a loop).
So, to summarize, my question is: How do I redirect page requests from "mydomain.com" to "mydomain.com/version10.7/index.html" without allowing the content to be reachable via "mydomain.com/production/version10.7/index.html" too?
Bonus question: Why does the removal of the condition
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/production/

cause an internal server error instead of allowing the following RewriteRule to redirect all requests to the files in /production/version10.7/ ?

Regarding the bonus question - because the pattern ^(.*)$ matches production/... again, so you have a rewrite loop there, that will eventually run into the internal rewrite limit.

A simply additional redirect from /production/... to /... should fix your issue, no?

You are probably right. I had to solves this another way by restructuring the paths, so I can't test it now, but your comment explaining the loop is probably correct. Thank you.
